# when is the layout of a PreferenceFragment filled?

Tags: android, preferencefragment

I have a `PreferenceFragment` with an `EditTextPreference`, where the user can specify a `textSize`. I want to display the summary of this preference in the current `textSize`. I managed to change the `textSize` of the summary after the preference has changed like this:

```
public class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {


 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        super.onPause();
    }


    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        float size = Float.parseFloat(sharedPreferences.getString("size","-1"));

        if(size>0) {
            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) getView();
            ListView listView = (ListView) linearLayout.getChildAt(0);
            LinearLayout linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout) listView.getChildAt(1);
            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) linearLayout1.getChildAt(1);
            TextView summary = (TextView) relativeLayout.getChildAt(1);
            summary.setTextSize(size);
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm not able to set it when the `PreferenceFragment` screen is shown. I have tried after `addPreferencesFromResource` and in the `onResume`(after `super`) but at both times the `ListView` is still empty.
Does anyone know when it is filled?